# namespace "Detours" has no member "uint8_t"

Tags: c++

I have been trying to create a dll program for a game called csgo. But my main problem is that it wont work until I have fixed this bug.

```
<namespace "Detours" has no member "uint8_t">
```

It happend right here:

```
oEndScene = (EndScene)Detours::X86::DetourFunction((Detours::uint8_t*)d3d9Device[42], (Detours::uint8_t*)hkEndScene);
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 3):

Detour namespace doesn't define a `uint8_t` type (since it is from Microsoft, I think they'll name it something like `USHORT`). It is available in the STL in the global namespace. So to resolve this, dont specify where (which namespace) the type comes from,

```cpp
oEndScene = (EndScene)Detours::X86::DetourFunction((uint8_t*)d3d9Device[42], (uint8_t*)hkEndScene);
```

And make sure to include `stdint.h` or `inttypes.h` header file to get the type.

Additional: Use `reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>()` instead of `(uint8_t*)`.

Comment: it doesn't work when I use "reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*<()".

Comment: @Nikodior If it doesn't work, then it *can* be a good thing. Which means that if you try to do it the normal way, you *might* end up with a runtime error. Check the types of `d3d9Device[42]` and `hkEndScene` and see if it can be casted to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
#include <cstdint>
```

then remove the "Detours" part of "Detours::uint8_t". Just use the regular uint8_t, I don't think you need the wrapper.